# Testing third party authentication flows with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing an Espresso test for an `Activity` which contains a button used for authenticating using a Google account and a button used for authenticating using a Facebook account. In my test I would like to simulate clicks on each of these buttons and ensure that it launches the correct component provided by these third parties.

It seems that there are two possible options:

1. Simulate a click on the appropriate button and ensure the UI contains the expected views.
2. Simulate a click on the appropriate button and ensure the correct `Intent` was fired.

I've initially opted for option #2, as I have found that it is difficult to test the UI with components outside of the `Activity` under test.

To start, I created a test for the Google button. The code is below:

```
@Test
public void testGoogleAuthButton() {
    // Start the Activity under test.
    activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());

    // Click the Google button.
    onView(withId(R.id.googleSignUpButton)).perform(click());

    // Ensure the `SignInHubActivity`, an `Activity` provided by the Google APIs, was launched.
    intended(hasComponent(SignInHubActivity.class.getName()), times(1));

    // Simulate a press on the back button to close the account chooser.
    UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).pressBack();
}
```

This test passes, however I am unsure as to whether or not this is the correct way to perform this test. Next, I tried a similar technique for the Facebook button:

```
@Test                                                                  
public void testFacebookAuthButton() {                                 
    // Start the Activity under test.                           
    activityRule.launchActivity(intent);                               

    // Simulate a click on the Facebook button.                                                                   
    onView(withId(R.id.facebookSignUpButton)).perform(click());        

    // Ensure the `FacebookActivity`, an `Activity` provided by the Facebook APIs, was launched.                                                                   
    intended(hasComponent(FacebookActivity.class.getName()), times(1));

    // Simulate a press on the back button to close the current Activity.                                                                   
    UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).pressBack();                                           

}
```

Strangely, this test fails, and notes that no `Intent`s were matched and that none were recorded.

My questions:

1. Does the code shown above represent the correct way to test these flows?
2. Why does the Facebook version of the test shown above fail, while the Google version does not?

Comment: How are you certain that is the component name in the intent and not a later activity after the initial intent is launched?

Comment: @dazza5000 The `ActivityManager` prints the name of an `Activity` to the log once it starts.

Comment: Are you using IntentsTestRule?